# Change Label and Image with Button, Tkinter - Error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm playing a little bit with Python and tkinter in order to learn a little bit of programming. I wanted to try and create a Frame with a label, an image and a button. By clicking the button label-text and image should change, where a specific text and image are matched.

Changing the text was no problem, but changing the image doesnt work, and I dont really get why. I add the code to show how I've tried it.
I get the error:

"_tkinter.TclError: image "dummy_logo2" doesn't exist"

What is the problem here? 
What am I overlooking?

```
root = tk.Tk()

dummy_logo2 = tk.PhotoImage(master=root, file='bell2.gif')
dummy_logo2 = dummy_logo2.subsample(5)
dummy_logo = tk.PhotoImage(master=root, file='bell.gif')
dummy_logo = dummy_logo.subsample(5)

dict_01 = {'eins':'dummy_logo',
           'zwei':'dummy_logo',
           'drei':'dummy_logo2',
           'vier':'dummy_logo2'}

def choose():
    exerc = random.choice(list(dict_01.keys()))
    label_01.config(text=exerc)
    label_02.config(image=dict_01[exerc])


label_01 = tk.Label(root, text='Dummy Text')
label_01.grid(row=1, column=1)
label_02 = tk.Label(root, image=dummy_logo)
label_02.grid(row=1, column=2)

button_01 = tk.Button(root, text='Choose', command=choose)
button_01.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you try `dict_01 = {'eins':dummy_logo,
           'zwei':dummy_logo,
           'drei':dummy_logo2,
           'vier':dummy_logo2}`

Comment: Okay, that really does solve the problem. I don't really get why, though, cause I tried before to change the image without the button, but still by using the values of that same dictionary and it worked with 'dummy_log'.

Comment: I am not sure who voted to close this as off topic but as far as I can tell this is on topic and a perfectly valid question with a simple to test MRE.

Answer (score 2):

`dict_01` is mapping names to the *names* of your images, as opposed to the images themselves.  Remove the quotes around them, like so:

```
dict_01 = {'eins':dummy_logo, 
           'zwei':dummy_logo, 
           'drei':dummy_logo2, 
           'vier':dummy_logo2}
```